# GulpUglifyError using gulp-webpack-vs2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am having following error

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ({) (line: 15, col: 7, pos: 1014)
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\..\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:1:0), <anonymous>:1545:18)
```

package.json

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.1.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.1.1",
"gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"uglify-js-harmony": "^2.6.2"
```

After looking for answers it looks like gulp-uglify relies on UglifyJS [Issue with Babel, ES6 and Uglify](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/146), thus it does not work properly. On the other hand they encourage to use uglify-js-harmony instead. But still is looking at gulp-uglify\node_modules\uglify-js. How can I force gulp to point to uglify-js-harmony instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related with my other question [Gulp error with angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370893/gulp-error-with-angular2), also it is necessary to deploy only needed files, or in the above case exclude node modules folder as:

tsconfig.json

```
"files": [
    "angularApp/app/app.module.ts",
    "angularApp/main.ts"
  ],
```

or excluding (better include only need files rather than excluding all node modules)

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```